# Rebus - Execute action before message is handled

Tags: log4net, rebus

Is there a way on [Rebus](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus) of executing an action before the IHandleMessages.Handle is called?

Particulary I want to set a correlation id of my logs for log4net and I'm having really difficult times to get this working.

I have an activity pattern converter to get a Guid from

`System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId = Guid.NewGuid()`

But I want to be able to set this before each handle is activated.
I'm using Autofac as container with Rebus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy and convenient way to achieve this would be to include the [Rebus.Events package](https://github.com/rebus-org/rebus.events), which allows for setting up an event delegate to be invoked before each message is handled like this:

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Events(e =>
    {
        e.BeforeMessageHandled += (bus, headers, message, context, args) =>
        {
            // do what you want in here :)
        };
    });
```

Comment: you have no idea how easy you are making my life :)
Love this transport!
Tested and works like a charm

Comment: When is Rebus.Events planned to be released as a stable package? Still in beta

Comment: well.... when enough people have tried it and given me their verdict I will release it – is the prerelease status an impediment to you?

Comment: not at all, at the moment I'm only using it for the above functionality and the first tests are looking god. I will keep pushing it more during the next weeks :)

Comment: Excellent! I am looking forward to hearing how it goes 

Comment: Is there a way of having in the DI context on the handler?
Situation is that the message I receive contains information for a lookup of  databases, ie: based on the GUID of the organisation set on the message I need my repositories to connect to an different databases. I use autofac and I want to set in the current scope the right resolver of my database

Comment: All Rebus container adapters allow for injecting `IMessageContext`, allowing you to access lots of interesting things about the message currently being handled

Comment: I had some issues with this, but got this working. I get the information I want from at e.BeforeMessageHandled += (bus, headers, message, context, args) => {} but this is called after the container already resolved all my references, so I had to implement some lazy loading of the parameters I needed.

Comment: Just an update on this, the application is deployed for more than 1 month already, without any issues using Rebus.Events. Really glad with all the work you do

Comment: It makes me really happy to hear that :)